# ¿Obtener imágenes de vídeos instagram?

Tags: jquery, instagram-api

Que tal, tengo un trozo de código que utilizo para llamar imagenes mediante hashtag

```
$("#instagram .center").append("<div class='instagram-wrap' id='pic-"+ data.data[i].id +"' ><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><span class='likes'>"+data.data[i].likes.count +"</span><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a></div>
```

Dentro del data , obtengo todo el JSon mi pregunta va de lado a obtener una "Vista previa" del video y que este me redireccione.

Para las imagenes lo hago con lo siguiente

```
data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url
```

En video como es posible eso? Gracias

Adjunto un poco de JSON porque es demaciado

```
{"pagination":{"next_max_tag_id":"AQBCrtMNYrMMxbSQWSZxZmqOnIzQ_D2bvRL5FdTGJPguFBgxcpdXk2TZK9VFBNxnR75KQZI4zgDtemEsRnK0NZoKFHZ1xyga7TFboHUjzehoZTDExZDtY_jzSHBy-U3-I3o","deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead","next_max_id":"AQBCrtMNYrMMxbSQWSZxZmqOnIzQ_D2bvRL5FdTGJPguFBgxcpdXk2TZK9VFBNxnR75KQZI4zgDtemEsRnK0NZoKFHZ1xyga7TFboHUjzehoZTDExZDtY_jzSHBy-U3-I3o","next_min_id":"AQAxnGnEFwu2C9iWMj08Kg1ZWdGGT3kZw31kU2KqDt0Xgn0oMz0E634N0lpH2Ahtsj0EzxDIDJ9qfXV55iV-Gws6V8v3pvpXg8BAi47i9MFezdvIfsPbIKxAxzugmY_cBck","min_tag_id":"AQAxnGnEFwu2C9iWMj08Kg1ZWdGGT3kZw31kU2KqDt0Xgn0oMz0E634N0lpH2Ahtsj0EzxDIDJ9qfXV55iV-Gws6V8v3pvpXg8BAi47i9MFezdvIfsPbIKxAxzugmY_cBck","next_url":"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/video/media/recent?access_token=3433927092.e029fea.37b15eb3e6784fec9ecd0b0d85b99f92&callback=jQuery111108143690682556781_1470762345814&_=1470762345815&max_tag_id=AQBCrtMNYrMMxbSQWSZxZmqOnIzQ_D2bvRL5FdTGJPguFBgxcpdXk2TZK9VFBNxnR75KQZI4zgDtemEsRnK0NZoKFHZ1xyga7TFboHUjzehoZTDExZDtY_jzSHBy-U3-I3o"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"attribution":null,"videos":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13960017_160060187757456_1539714693_s.mp4","width":480,"height":480},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13943922_103579940091222_649570191_n.mp4","width":640,"height":640},"low_bandwidth":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13960017_160060187757456_1539714693_s.mp4","width":480,"height":480}},"tags":["flume","art","instagram","contemporaryart","instalike","trippy","edm","instabeauty","video","alunageorge","electronic","modernart","psychedelic","artist","instagood","music",""],"type":"video","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762338","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UxkDAQ1E/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/13714166_225918094470935_1390836244_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjEzMzI0NDg5ODYyOA%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/13714166_225918094470935_1390836244_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjEzMzI0NDg5ODYyOA%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/13714166_225918094470935_1390836244_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjEzMzI0NDg5ODYyOA%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762338","text":"Visual via @ask__the__dust \nMusic: Flume - Innocence (feat. AlunaGeorge)\n\n@flumemusic @alunageorge #music #edm #Electronic # #art #artist #psychedelic #video #contemporaryart #modernart #trippy #flume #alunageorge #instabeauty #instagram #instagood #instalike","from":{"username":"savact","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11420458_1621526818124949_1617384913_a.jpg","id":"305094681","full_name":"Savannah Thomas"},"id":"17859436669063921"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172133244898628_305094681","user":{"username":"savact","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11420458_1621526818124949_1617384913_a.jpg","id":"305094681","full_name":"Savannah Thomas"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["dırectorofphotography","6d","lasterrenassamana","phatom4","direccion","director","thanksgod","video","4k","workinghard","playaportillo","filmmaker","canonphotography"],"type":"image","location":{"latitude":19.324435408298,"name":"Playa Portillo, Las Terrenas","longitude":-69.494962947072,"id":234380407},"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762334","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UxA5AYx1/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13739541_120222395089571_1515634005_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA5NTQ5NjE5NTE4OQ%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13739541_120222395089571_1515634005_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA5NTQ5NjE5NTE4OQ%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13739541_120222395089571_1515634005_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA5NTQ5NjE5NTE4OQ%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762334","text":"#lasterrenassamana #playaportillo #ThanksGod #Filmmaker #direccion #video #Director #Phatom4 #4K #Filmmaker #6D #ThanksGod #workinghard #canonphotography #dırectorofphotography","from":{"username":"alexandertm05","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13549340_249742108741789_330655129_a.jpg","id":"359982001","full_name":"Alexander Tejeda"},"id":"17850679747108613"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172095496195189_359982001","user":{"username":"alexandertm05","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13549340_249742108741789_330655129_a.jpg","id":"359982001","full_name":"Alexander Tejeda"}},{"attribution":null,"videos":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13961592_773975116038220_2062255286_s.mp4","width":480,"height":600},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13961592_773975116038220_2062255286_s.mp4","width":480,"height":600},"low_bandwidth":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13961592_773975116038220_2062255286_s.mp4","width":480,"height":600}},"tags":["videoshoot","videogram","videochat","igvid","instagramvideo","videostar","videoclip","instavideo","videoinstagram","igvideo","video","videooftheday","bestvideooftheday","videograms","instavid","videodiaries","videography","vid","videoke","videos","instavideos","videogramer"],"type":"video","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762327","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UwPNgbB8/","likes":{"count":1},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/13741298_1400860259927936_1160465976_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA0MjE1MzA0NjE0MA%3D%3D.2.l","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/c0.76.612.612/13774220_131221637320935_1652415185_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA0MjE1MzA0NjE0MA%3D%3D.2.c","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/13741298_1400860259927936_1160465976_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA0MjE1MzA0NjE0MA%3D%3D.2.l","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762327","text":"New high score. Dont ask me how\n\n#video #instavideo #videos #videoshoot #instagramvideo #videoclip #videoinstagram #videostar #vid #instavideos #videogram #videograms #videooftheday #instavid #bestvideooftheday #igvideo #igvid #videodiaries #videography #videochat #videoke #videogramer","from":{"username":"beastofbgate","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13636269_307970099551340_1437417343_a.jpg","id":"494724096","full_name":"Ruan Duvenage"},"id":"17860433890015778"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172042153046140_494724096","user":{"username":"beastofbgate","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13636269_307970099551340_1437417343_a.jpg","id":"494724096","full_name":"Ruan Duvenage"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["tomboy","gayclub","losangeles","art","gay","promo","marketing","photography","hiphop","weho","video","imvufinest","atlanta","lesbo","imvulesbians","like4like","imvucelebrity","blacklesbians","imvu","promoter","musicvideo","newyork","studswaggladoc","music","tomboistyle","interview","new","hollywood","pride","l4l"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762331","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UwtYggWV/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13687281_1228691057174937_15161940_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA3NDU0OTg3MjAyMQ%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13687281_1228691057174937_15161940_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA3NDU0OTg3MjAyMQ%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13687281_1228691057174937_15161940_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA3NDU0OTg3MjAyMQ%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762331","text":"VIDEO LINK IN BIO. .UVE BEEN WAITING ON THIS ONE. .\n#studswaggLADoc #art #like4like #gayclub #losangeles #hollywood #imvu #video #musicvideo #new #music #weho #tomboistyle #tomboy #promo #promoter #imvufinest #atlanta #losangeles #imvucelebrity #marketing #photography #lesbo #pride #hiphop #interview #l4l #gay #imvulesbians #blacklesbians #newyork","from":{"username":"studimvumovies","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13706872_1768298833445298_1345788946_a.jpg","id":"3629854937","full_name":"VIDEOS OF SHORT DREAMS ♀VU"},"id":"17860672255061496"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172074549872021_3629854937","user":{"username":"studimvumovies","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13706872_1768298833445298_1345788946_a.jpg","id":"3629854937","full_name":"VIDEOS OF SHORT DREAMS ♀VU"}},{"attribution":null,"videos":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13927637_278610822503714_1895131483_s.mp4","width":480,"height":270},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13943059_1631370480511037_498868633_n.mp4","width":640,"height":360},"low_bandwidth":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13927637_278610822503714_1895131483_s.mp4","width":480,"height":270}},"tags":["dark","salm","fire","pyrotechnics","fireworks","evil","musicvideo","fog","video","pyro","warehouse","deathmetal","brutaldeathmetal","deathcore","darkness"],"type":"video","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762328","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UwRPg0s1/","likes":{"count":1},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/13774426_315113762156435_1040772654_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA0NDMzNDE4OTM2NQ%3D%3D.2.l","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/c157.0.406.406/13739541_1745384359066818_1698373688_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA0NDMzNDE4OTM2NQ%3D%3D.2.c","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/13774426_315113762156435_1040772654_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjA0NDMzNDE4OTM2NQ%3D%3D.2.l","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762328","text":"NEW MUSIC VIDEO! HEAD OVER TO OUR FB PAGE AND CHECK IT OUT: www.facebook.com/WithinDestructionSlo/\n\n#salm #deathcore #deathmetal #brutaldeathmetal #musicvideo #video #darkness #dark #warehouse #fire #fireworks #pyro #pyrotechnics #fog #evil","from":{"username":"withindestructiondm","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12224659_478698988968735_1424626959_a.jpg","id":"980994588","full_name":"Within Destruction"},"id":"17850534412113890"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172044334189365_980994588","user":{"username":"withindestructiondm","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12224659_478698988968735_1424626959_a.jpg","id":"980994588","full_name":"Within Destruction"}},{"attribution":null,"videos":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13961495_1085755528138427_424192594_s.mp4","width":480,"height":600},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13961495_1085755528138427_424192594_s.mp4","width":480,"height":600},"low_bandwidth":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13961495_1085755528138427_424192594_s.mp4","width":480,"height":600}},"tags":["love","instagram","happy","photo","goodtimes","goodnight","instago","likes","smile","follow","instadaily","friends","friendship","sun","instagood","bestoftheday","video","like4like","my","instamood","photooftheday"],"type":"video","location":{"latitude":40.3953,"name":"Baku, Azerbaijan","longitude":49.8822,"id":217690101},"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Sierra","created_time":"1470762318","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UvIOjDbr/","likes":{"count":2},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/13827247_583989525114937_2044968071_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk2NTkzNDg0MzYyNw%3D%3D.2.l","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/c0.76.612.612/13714096_285174875179766_1849773824_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk2NTkzNDg0MzYyNw%3D%3D.2.c","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/13827247_583989525114937_2044968071_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk2NTkzNDg0MzYyNw%3D%3D.2.l","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762318","text":"Axşamıvız xeyir olsun\n#instadaily #instamood #instagood #instagram #instago #goodnight #goodtimes #photooftheday #photo #bestoftheday #my #love #likes #like4like #follow #smile #happy #sun #friendship #friends #video #instagood","from":{"username":"hamid_officiall","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13422920_259021134470147_658323239_a.jpg","id":"831910622","full_name":"Meyxana (Əhmədli məktəbi)"},"id":"17851626940076843"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313171965934843627_831910622","user":{"username":"hamid_officiall","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13422920_259021134470147_658323239_a.jpg","id":"831910622","full_name":"Meyxana (Əhmədli məktəbi)"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["followforfollow","tag","video","skyporn","striker"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762326","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UwEJj7s5/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13731401_1203501859671988_225714601_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAzMDI3NTY5NzQ2NQ%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13731401_1203501859671988_225714601_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAzMDI3NTY5NzQ2NQ%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/13731401_1203501859671988_225714601_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAzMDI3NTY5NzQ2NQ%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762326","text":"qо aа\nсxй0лиq9 #striker пъ8\nаvyзыт #skyporn 2t\no8bбшаej  #video йкббпhfdи\nd5\nnь #tag lмз\n8kwaс \nr\nqз\n #followforfollow","from":{"username":"jasmin._sabkoot","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg","id":"3642475472","full_name":""},"id":"17850547309082893"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172030275697465_3642475472","user":{"username":"jasmin._sabkoot","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg","id":"3642475472","full_name":""}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["photo","myinstagramtour","video","postwedding","lombokisland"],"type":"image","location":{"latitude":-8.725693095,"name":"Gili Kedis - Honeymoon Island, Lombok","longitude":116.027832735,"id":381326559},"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762324","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UvywATty/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13636236_1674649132854697_843521264_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAxMTU5MzMxNzIzNA%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13636236_1674649132854697_843521264_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAxMTU5MzMxNzIzNA%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13636236_1674649132854697_843521264_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAxMTU5MzMxNzIzNA%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762324","text":"Shahrul & Farra #postwedding #lombokisland #photo #video #myinstagramtour","from":{"username":"abdrahman","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/10661227_786659648087115_1104218298_a.jpg","id":"19773251","full_name":"abdrahman"},"id":"17860201090016811"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172011593317234_19773251","user":{"username":"abdrahman","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/10661227_786659648087115_1104218298_a.jpg","id":"19773251","full_name":"abdrahman"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["body","summer","hairstyle","fashion","hairdresser","fashionista","streetstyle","curves","video","makeup","fotography","girl","sport","wishlist","perfect","x","nights","make","clothes","all_shots","curvy","moda","amazing","fashionstyle","fun","smile","holiday","fashionblogger","nails","happy"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762323","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UvuigNTN/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13767582_183973318683159_539915324_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAwNzA3MTgzMTI0NQ%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13767582_183973318683159_539915324_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAwNzA3MTgzMTI0NQ%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13767582_183973318683159_539915324_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MjAwNzA3MTgzMTI0NQ%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762323","text":"❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤#hairdresser #hairstyle #holiday #summer #fashion #girl #sport #video #perfect #fun #happy  #moda #smile #fotography #nights #amazing #all_shots #fashionista #streetstyle #body #curvy #fashionblogger #wishlist #curves #fashionstyle #clothes #make #makeup #nails #x","from":{"username":"deryaemel61","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13768361_701148543356763_787141471_a.jpg","id":"1150140560","full_name":"EMEL DERYA"},"id":"17859638170020198"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313172007071831245_1150140560","user":{"username":"deryaemel61","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13768361_701148543356763_787141471_a.jpg","id":"1150140560","full_name":"EMEL DERYA"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["mini","canvas","art","simply","process","creative","video","mixedmedia"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762319","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UvM7Bb2L/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13694526_309831562699349_318747983_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk3MDk3NTk3Mjc0Nw%3D%3D.2.l","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c113.0.854.854/13704107_1128312617215334_271643523_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk3MDk3NTk3Mjc0Nw%3D%3D.2.c","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13694526_309831562699349_318747983_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk3MDk3NTk3Mjc0Nw%3D%3D.2.l","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762319","text":"Made these baby canvases. They are so cute  pretty happy with the out come. I Just went go with the flow. There is a process video online!!! Link in bio!! #simply #creative #mixedmedia #art #process #video #mini #canvas","from":{"username":"simplycreativekyra","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13531833_1071511262927527_1577424969_a.jpg","id":"2997508799","full_name":"Kyra Pace"},"id":"17860251667029814"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313171970975972747_2997508799","user":{"username":"simplycreativekyra","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13531833_1071511262927527_1577424969_a.jpg","id":"2997508799","full_name":"Kyra Pace"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["nom","art","love","foodporn","food","sweet","movenpick","cheerful","hkig","design","igers","video","foodie","girl","ig","like","style","youtuber","mood","healthy","hongkong","cooking","youtube","icecream","yum","caramel","cookaka","potd","happy"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":1},"filter":"Ludwig","created_time":"1470762279","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5UqWJgRtK/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13734487_317748985231632_160167951_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTYzNzI4NTIzMTQzNA%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13734487_317748985231632_160167951_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTYzNzI4NTIzMTQzNA%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13734487_317748985231632_160167951_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTYzNzI4NTIzMTQzNA%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762279","text":"give myself a little treat","from":{"username":"_cookaka","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/924511_1415922922029901_180366740_a.jpg","id":"1408883768","full_name":"cookaka"},"id":"17850406348084931"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313171637285231434_1408883768","user":{"username":"_cookaka","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/924511_1415922922029901_180366740_a.jpg","id":"1408883768","full_name":"cookaka"}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["hongkong","swag","video","tour","design"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762317","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5Uu71A_Ah/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13732274_1734008916848352_1926697567_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk1MjYyMTU4MDMyMQ%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13732274_1734008916848352_1926697567_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk1MjYyMTU4MDMyMQ%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/13732274_1734008916848352_1926697567_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTk1MjYyMTU4MDMyMQ%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762317","text":"т\nрп8всvу\njуx\nъц  #swag е5yя0й\nбmорkуу #tour 3\n\n0\n70\n\nчeb\nm  #hongkong zmхф \nнпнч оw #video бк6m 2\nышy0nw \nr\nd #design","from":{"username":"alannah___safonovasz","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg","id":"3641464866","full_name":""},"id":"17859745414012595"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313171952621580321_3641464866","user":{"username":"alannah___safonovasz","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg","id":"3641464866","full_name":""}},{"attribution":null,"tags":["marketingdigital","publicidad","smartphones","tablet","inversión","viral","marketing","publicidadonline","anuncio","socialmediamarketing","méxico","video","mobilemarketing","redessociales","publicidaddigital"],"type":"image","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762309","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5Ut_xATqf/","likes":{"count":0},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/13712776_1163167260391711_875192465_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTg4ODEyOTc4NDQ3OQ%3D%3D.2","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13712776_1163167260391711_875192465_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTg4ODEyOTc4NDQ3OQ%3D%3D.2","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13712776_1163167260391711_875192465_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTg4ODEyOTc4NDQ3OQ%3D%3D.2","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762309","text":"La publicidad incrementó 36% en el último año, sumando una inversión de 14,936 millones de pesos. >> www.designnet.com.mx\n\n#publicidad #publicidadonline #mobilemarketing #publicidaddigital #anuncio #smartphones #tablet #méxico #socialmediamarketing #video #viral #inversión #redessociales #marketing #marketingdigital","from":{"username":"designnetmx","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13724676_1763606860584198_762907564_a.jpg","id":"3059480903","full_name":"Designnet Mx"},"id":"17854631878065517"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313171888129784479_3059480903","user":{"username":"designnetmx","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13724676_1763606860584198_762907564_a.jpg","id":"3059480903","full_name":"Designnet Mx"}},{"attribution":null,"videos":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13948970_641626389327107_777419953_s.mp4","width":480,"height":270},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13998309_1599901840309815_74207049_n.mp4","width":640,"height":360},"low_bandwidth":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13948970_641626389327107_777419953_s.mp4","width":480,"height":270}},"tags":["beautiful","hip","life","musically","flow","canon","videoclip","nuevo","hiphop","video","rap","new","videooftheday","makeit","rapero","raplife","jotaeme","working","hiphoplife","rapper","musicvideo","camera","musica","hop","rapline","music","preview","rapmusic","nice"],"type":"video","location":null,"comments":{"count":0},"filter":"Normal","created_time":"1470762308","link":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BI5Utz7gQfU/","likes":{"count":1},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/13774603_1783835658499490_1064418153_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTg3NTQyMTAzMDM1Ng%3D%3D.2.l","width":320,"height":320},"thumbnail":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/c157.0.406.406/13724579_1160140510709728_1148041383_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTg3NTQyMTAzMDM1Ng%3D%3D.2.c","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/13774603_1783835658499490_1064418153_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxMzE3MTg3NTQyMTAzMDM1Ng%3D%3D.2.l","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1470762308","text":"Cuestión de honor. RAP, CORAZON E INTELECTO JOTAEME IS MUSIC. @jotaeme21 @infiniti_fotografia #rap #life  #hiphop #music #musica #videoclip #beautiful  #camera #nice #canon #hiphoplife #working #musically #hip #hop #rapper #rapero #rapmusic #video #musicvideo #raplife #rapline #jotaeme #makeit #video #flow #new #nuevo #preview #videooftheday","from":{"username":"andrea_fernandez21","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/10547356_1523135527905798_1975730864_a.jpg","id":"1444895052","full_name":"Andrea Fernandez Ordoñez"},"id":"17863601206031371"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"1313171875421030356_1444895052","user":{"username":"andrea_fernandez21","profile_picture":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/10547356_1523135527905798_1975730864_a.jpg","id":"1444895052","full_name":"Andrea Fernandez Ordoñez"}},{"attribution":null,"videos":{"low_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13953537_1749534751968821_227162345_s.mp4","width":480,"height":269},"standard_resolution":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13948879_1767745910132233_77104776_n.mp4","width":640,"height":359},"low_bandwidth":{"url":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13953537_1749534751968821_227162345_s.mp4","width":480,"height":269}},"tags":
```

Mi criterio de búsqueda es

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+hashtag+"/media/recent/?access_token="+access_token;
```

Comment: ¿lo que quieres el la miniatura del video?

Comment: @rnd Si mas o menos, por ejemplo la pagina 
[enlace](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hashtag/)
Trae consigo tanto imagenes como videos, pero no se sabe hasta que le das clic. Viendo un poco de lo que muestra en el inspector, trae imagenes.

Comment: @Irwing, gracias por actualizar tu pregunta; cuando decía "criterio", me refiero también a: **¿qué deseas obtener exactamente, (solo las fotos y los videos)?**, estoy viendo el JSON, pero no comprendo si quieres obtener todas las imágenes y videos (que por cierto, vienen en `"resoluciones baja, estándar y bajo ancho de banda"`).

Comment: @Mauricio Si Claro, La solución a mi problema fue mediante un hashtag obtener todo lo referente a eso( Videos e imagenes) la resolución, el ancho de banda, en este momento no me interesa. Como comente en mi pregunta, unicamente puedo obtener imagenes en este momento, pero aun no puedo obtener "imagenes de videos", no se si se deba a la forma de obtener el JSON

Comment: @Irwing prueba `standard-resolution.url` = esta es la imagen de la vista previa del video. Acabo de probar buscando en el JSON. Así como obtienes la imagen, prueba de esta manera: `data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url.`.

Comment: @Mauricio :o Muchas gracias, llevaba todo el día viendo esta cosa, aunque no se a que se deba esto? Tiene que ver con algo en especifico?

Comment: @Irwing, puede ser, tal vez no viste detenidamente "suele pasar", Si mi respuesta te sirvió, te pido el favor de aceptarla. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Mauricio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Siguiendo el objeto JSON que has proporcionado en tu pregunta:*

Para obtener la imagen de la vista previa de un video, prueba lo siguiente:

```
data[i].images.standard_resolution.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Videos</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video width="480" height="480" controls>
    <source src="http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4" 
      type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar, lo que pasa es que obtengo los datos mediante un JSON y solo quiero que se muestren imagenes y estos me redireccionen al post, ya sea imagen o video.

Lo que me muestas ya lo había intentado pero me trae el video y es lo que no quiero :D